# How can I add vector tiles to my tileserver?

Tags: openstreetmap, vector, tiles, vector-tiles

I created my own tileserver under ubuntu 12.04 as described here:

http://switch2osm.org/serving-tiles/building-a-tile-server-from-packages/

now I want to serve the tiles as vectors, I found this:
https://github.com/mapbox/mapnik-vector-tile

but I dont know if I can use it right now. I installed the dependencies but when building the make command does not work at the installation because
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
is shown.

Comment: Your `make` error message indicates that you are in the wrong directory. You need to switch to the one where the *Makefile* is located.

Comment: the directory wasnt switched, so I think there was a previous error and because of that the makefile wasnt created.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a default solution, as usually everybody uses plain raster maps (TMS or WMS), so IMHO there is just a hand full of people (mapbox) who can help you to setup this solution (even at http://help.osm.org but call me wrong). Sorry, but I guess you need to find out on your own how it fits together :( https://www.mapbox.com/blog/vector-tiles/

For other aproaches at this topic, see https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Vector_tiles AFAIK none of them is ready to use ...